# How does Matlab calculate the perimeter using regionprops of a rectangular picture

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to calculate the perimeter of a "almost" round (or elliptical) object. I use two ways:

First method:

```
stats = regionprops('table',bw,'Centroid',...
'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength','Perimeter');
perimeter_matlab=stats.Perimeter; %get the perimeter using matlab regionprops
```

Second method:

```
stats2 = regionprops(L,'Area','Centroid');

for k = 1:length(B)
    % obtain (X,Y) boundary coordinates corresponding to label 'k'
    boundary = B{k};

    %get the perimeter by calculating the each pixel to pixel distance in boundary and add the discret distand together
    delta_sq = diff(boundary).^2;
    perimeter_pixel= sum(sqrt(sum(delta_sq,2)));
end
```

Results:

When I'm using a rectangular object like `900*600` pixel and its perimeter should be `900*2+598*2=2996`  but 
`perimeter_matlab=2935.7` Why does it go wrong?
`perimeter_pixel = 2996`  is correct.

And when I'm using a circle with radius of `50` pixel (diameter is `101`) and its perimeter should be `2*pi*50=314.1593`  but 
`perimeter_matlab=313.904` which is close to the answer, but
`perimeter_pixel = 332.0488`  why does it go wrong?

How does Matlab calculate the `perimeter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what algorithm MATLAB uses, but I can tell you why your pixel to pixel distance overestimates the boundary length: because the image is defined on a regular grid, the polygon you get by stringing together the boundary pixels is not as smooth as the continuous-domain circle that you are trying to measure. The jaggedness causes the polygon boundary to be longer. Algorithms that compensate for this tend to assume circular-shaped objects, and therefore minimize the error for circles. This compensation then causes an underestimation of the boundary length for squares. Nonetheless, if you measure the boundary of squares with an arbitrary angle, you'd end up with an accurate estimate using this compensation. The single square aligned with the grid just happens to be a worst case scenario.

For a more in-depth explanation of the algorithm and choices involved see [this blog post](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/310).

---

EDIT:

Now I know what algorithm MATLAB uses. There is a property called `'PerimeterOld'`, which implements the naive method that you also tried. That is, it uses weights of 1 for horizontal or vertical steps, and weights of `sqrt(2)` for diagonal steps. A property called `'Perimeter'`, which you are using and has the behavior that you found unexpected, uses the algorithm by Vossepoel and Smeulders as I described in the link I gave above:

```
% (Code copy-pasted from regionprops.m
%  Copyright 1993-2014 The MathWorks, Inc.
%  Provided here as "fair use" for instructional purposes, don't
%  use this code, use the equivalent code on my blog instead.)
function perimeter = computePerimeterFromBoundary(B)
delta = diff(B).^2;
if(size(delta,1) > 1)
    isCorner  = any(diff([delta;delta(1,:)]),2); % Count corners.
    isEven    = any(~delta,2);
    perimeter = sum(isEven)*0.980 + sum(~isEven)*1.406 - sum(isCorner)*0.091;
else
    perimeter = 0; % if the number of pixels is 1 or less.
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Now I understand the main reason. Next step to solve this problem is to find the algorithm of these kind of code to know how they compensate these error and to take a look. Thanks again !

Comment: @Melissa I found the relevant bit of code that is used by `regionprops`. I've edited my answer. I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Now I understand that the Vossepoel and Smeulders method has its weight for the perimeter. Is most people using this way to calculate circle-shape object ?

Comment: @Melissa It is the correct way to calculate the perimeter. Unfortunately there still are many people not aware of this method, who use the `1`,`sqrt(2)` weights, or worse yet, who simply count pixels. A way to show appreciation is to upvote my answer. ;)